# Optimizing SQLite Updates

Tags: c#, sqlite

```
Class Database {
    private SQLiteConnection myDB;
    private SQLiteCommand cmd;

    public Database {

        //create database file, create connection info,  etc)
        String sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 'myTable' (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, user TEXT, currency INTEGER DEFAULT 0)";

        using (cmd = new SQLiteCommand(sql, myDB))
        {
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }

    public void newUser(String user) {
         String sql = "INSERT INTO myTable (user) VALUES '" + user + "'";
         cmd = new SQLiteCommand(myDB, sql);
         cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }

    private bool userExists(String user) {
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM '" + channel + "';";
        using (cmd = new SQLiteCommand(sql, myDB))
        {
             using (SQLiteDataReader r = cmd.ExecuteReader())
             {
                  while (r.Read())
                  {    
                       if (r["user"].ToString().Equals(user, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                       {
                           return true;
                        }
                    }
              }
          }
          return false;
    }

    public void AddCurrency(String user, int amount) {
        if (!userExists(user)) {
            newUser(user);
        }
        using (cmd = myDB.CreateCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE '" + channel + "' SET currency = currency + @amount WHERE user = @user";
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@amount", amount));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@user", user));
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }

    }
}

Class Stuff {
    public void Main(String[] args) {
        Database db = new Database();

        //blah blah blah
        //blah blah blah
        //blah blah blah

        //Do stuff and generate an array called users that is alist of all the users in the channel

        //Here's what I currently do
        foreach (String person in users) {
            db.AddCurrency(person, 1);
        }       
    }
}
```

The problem with this, as you can probably see, is that with a large user list (say, 1000 users) is that I could be potentially doing up to 3000 queries.  It works fine on small scale, but when the user list gets too large, it really starts to bog down (particularly the write queries). So I'd like to change it to something like db.AddCurrency(users, 1); that sends the whole array, but I have other problems with that.  Such as, there doesn't seem to be an "Upsert" (Insert if not exists, update otherwise) type command in SQLite.  Any ideas on how I can reduce the run time on large user lists?

For reference, this is part of a chat bot for http://twitch.tv .  It's seems to work fine for all of my current users, even if they have up to 100 or 200 concurrent viewers.  But one day out of curiosity, I ran it in a stream with over 4k viewers, and it was taking like 2 minutes+ to do all of the database updates.  It's not a problem *now*, but I feel like it's something I want to fix if it's at all possible.

**Note:  I'm using the System.Data.SQLite library.

Comment: The formatting of your code sample is kind of messed up. You should clean it up to make it easier for people to read.

Comment: Bah, the 4 space blocks messed everything up.  Fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

Create indexes on your user and currency columns.

```
CREATE INDEX 'userName' ON 'tablename' ('user' ASC);
CREATE INDEX 'currencyAMT' on 'tablename' ('currency' ASC);
```

Pass these as separate commands in your database constructor, after your create table command. This should create indices on your columns. (I don't have SQLLite on my system ATM, so I didn't have the ability to test)

Also, in your userExists method, add a where clause to your SQL, so that you can get a recordset where the user = your passed in user.

```
"SELECT * FROM '" + channel + "' WHERE user = '" & user & "';";
```

If you don't get any records back, the user doesn't exist. If you do get a record back, the user does exist.

This will reduce your O(n) search to something more like O(1).

Comment: Let me know if you would like me to help you with the index syntax.

Comment: Yea I don't know what you mean by indexing the columns.  Please show me the syntax <3

Comment: Okay, gimmie some time.

Comment: Updated. The first set of single quotes can be anything. Its just the name of the index. Second quote is the table. Third quote is the column to index on, and then the sort order. Go and read up on indices in a general sense to know more about what this does.

Comment: I've done a bit of googling, and what I find says that indexing (probably) shouldn't be used when doing large or frequent batch inserts/updates.  The bot I'm writing could potentially be doing these updates every few minutes.

Comment: Oh yea, and I should note that I did some rudimentary performance tests.  Looping through 10000 userExists() queries takes less than a second.  Looping through 100 addCurrency() queries where none of the users exists already and have to be created by newUser() takes 15 seconds.  Looping through 100 addCurrency() queries where all of the users already exist takes that down to about 7 seconds.  So basically any INSERT or UPDATE queries seem to take roughly 70ms each.

Comment: Try your tests again with one million users. Then try the optimizations I presented to you.

Comment: I'm still not sure how to use the indices to speed up the writes.  I changed things around to doing the entire user list in 1 transaction (well, 2 - see http://privatepaste.com/8c37fbce77 ), which brought write time down on 10000 writes from 20+ minutes to 32 seconds, which is reasonable but I think should still be able to go faster.  And yea, I changed the userExists function based on your suggestion already.  The odd thing at this point is that 10000 INSERTs takes less than a second.  10000 UPDATEs takes 32 seconds.  Not sure why.

Comment: @Keirathi If you're at all doing lookups based on a column you should probably index it. Basically, if your table has `n` records, then without indexing you need to look at all of them. With indexing the lookup is `O(log n)` for a B-tree index, with a fairly high logarithm base. An insert has to update every index on the table, which once again should be an `O(log n)` operation. Not indexing a table only makes sense if it only ever has very few records in it (i.e. `log n` isn't much smaller than `n`), but you write to it very often, far more often than you query it.

Comment: Also, my gut says that updating an index over 4k records takes no time at all, but sequentially scanning them would require several disk reads if uncached. But only benchmarking will tell the truth. Also, this is a dataset small enough to fit into memory: are you sure you need to write everything to the database immediately? You could just keep the main data in memory and write things to the database in the background. This is a little more complex and prone to data loss but it would make your bot more responsive.